# How to get correct results from Regex.Split with groups

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to find a) All the parts of the input string that match a pattern; and b) All the parts of the input string that do not match the same pattern. I am using Regex.Matches to find the parts that match, and I am trying to use Regex.Split to remove the parts that match and leave me with the parts that do not match. The pattern is user defined so changing capturing groups to non-capturing groups is not acceptable.

So, I thought `Regex.Split` was supposed to **remove** the matching text and return an array of all the remaining parts of the string. For example, input string "abcd" with pattern "bc" will return a string array with 2 elements, "a" and "d".

But when you add groups to the pattern the results get all bogus. If you run this:

```
Regex.Split("abcd", "b(c)")
```

The results are:

```
a
c
d
```

Why is "c" showing up in the results of the split? It is part of the pattern that I want to split on. I'm using the same pattern to get matches and to split the string, so changing the group to a non-capturing group is not acceptable. Is there any way to actually split a string with a regex pattern (Regex.Split is obviously broken)?

======

Answer: It's not possible to get the parts of a string between pattern matches using Regex.Split if the pattern contains has capturing groups.

Answer (score 5):

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this function states:

> If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array. For example, if you split the string "plum-pear" on a hyphen placed within capturing parentheses, the returned array includes a string element that contains the hyphen.

so you want to remove this capturing group by adding `?:` to it :

```
Regex.Split("abcd", "b(?:c)")
```

If you don't want to change the expression but remove the capture, you should use another function:

- [Regex.Split Method (String, String, RegexOptions, TimeSpan)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160264%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Use the option : `ExplicitCapture` [See option page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: No, I don't want to remove the capturing group. I am using Regex.Matches and Regex.Split and I want to use the same pattern for both.

Comment: The `ExplicitCapture` solution doesn't work if the given regex might contain named capturing groups (because those would still be included). So it's not a safe solution if you have no control over the regex.

Answer (score 1):

That's the correct behavior according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4

Right above this snippet:

> If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array.

Comment: I get that it's by design, but as far as I'm concerned, it is broken by design.

Comment: @Nick No, it's not broken, because this is the default behavior, but not the only one. The design lets you choose if you want this behavior or not.

Comment: @Nick Given that sharing a regular expression between a `Split` and a `Match` is extremely rare (this is the first time I see this even suggested, let alone implemented) the design makes perfect sense.

Comment: How can you choose if you want this behavior or not? The behavior is it includes capturing groups instead of splitting the input string where the pattern matches, like it's name would imply. Changing capture groups to non-capture groups does not change this behavior, it just avoids it, as a (sometimes but not always feasible) work around for bizarre behavior.

Comment: @Nick The fact that you cannot understand something does not make it incorrect. Good luck!

Comment: In order to backreference a group it must be a capture group. The fact that capture groups are returned as items in the array of a split, means that you cannot use a regex pattern that contains a backreference to split the string properly. It has nothing to do with me not understanding why its happening, it is a bad design decision.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation

> If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any
>   captured text is 
>       included in the resulting string array. For example, if you split the string 
>       "plum-pear" on a hyphen placed within capturing parentheses, the returned array 
>       includes a string element that contains the hyphen.

Your definition of the match as b(c) causes c to be captured as a group and thus it is included in the result.  You instead need to match "bc", which will only match when bc appears.